# how to zoom-in on stage with actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, zooming

When playing a flash movie in a browser, we can right-click on stage and zoom in.

can we also code these as functions in our actionscript-3 file? like automatically zooming onto the stage at a particular point? can we do it when some key is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you decrease a display objects z property it will move closer to the 'camera' effectively zooming it.  To zoom into a particular position you'll have to move its x and y properties as well.  Other than the legacy supported 'zoom in'  on the right click menu there's no auto zoom functionality in flash.

Comment: thanks. I was trying to have the screen scroll effect for a platform game using this functionality. It would be really helpful for programmers instead of coding it separately. I think adobe should add this functionality through actionscript.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a Matrix to do this, [here's a simple example](http://bit.ly/4MnNIA)

Comment: nice. but this doesn't zoom-in (or out) on stage. it does on a different DisplayObject